# jquery basic content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to build very simple content slider but have no idea where to start, I have tried almost all of the free sliders out there and couldn't quite find one which suits my needs. Simply I have inline-block elements of the same width which I need to scroll with next and prev button. if the content is greater than the wrapper hide the rest content and when next button pressed show the rest content, and the same for previous button too. can someone at least get me started? here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RC33S/1/

```
<div class="main_wrapper">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
</div>
<button class="prev"><</button>
<button class="next">></button>
```

Comment: Find slider what works close to what you need. And study its source code. You'll get some ideas from that.

Answer (score 1):

Search for liquid slider.  I have used it a number of times successfully. Very configurable.